# Every k-cell is compact / alternative proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, alternative-proof

I have become really interested in trying to prove directly things that are more easily proved by contradiction. The below seems to be a good example of this. Rudin's proof makes perfect sense to me. In fact I think it is a very elegant proof. But nonetheless I am very much interested in a constructive proof.

Essentially Rudin proves that every k-cell is compact by assuming the opposite: that there is an open cover of a k-cell $I$ which does not contain a finite subcover. I would like to assume $\{G_\alpha \}$ is an arbitrary open cover of $I$ and show directly that $G_\alpha$ must have a finite subcover.

Here is an outline of Rudin's proof(Theorem 2.40):

Every k-cell is compact.

Proof. Let $I$ be a k-cell consisting of all points $x = (x_1, \dots, x_k)$ such that $a_j \leq x_j \leq b_j$ for $1 \leq j \leq k$. Put

$\delta = \{ \sum\limits_1^k(b_j - a_j)^2\}^{1/2}$

Then $|x-y| \leq \delta$ if $x, y \in I$.

Suppose there is an open cover $\{G_\alpha \}$ which contains no finite subcover. Put $c_j = \frac{a_j + b_j}{2}$. The intervals $[a_j, c_j]$ and $[c_j, b_j]$ determine $2^k$ k-cells whose union is $I$. At least one of these subsets of $I$, say $I_1$, cannot be covered by any finite subcollection of $\{ G_\alpha \}$. So we begin again with the k-cell $I_1$ and subdivide further to achieve a sequence of k-cells such that

(a) $I \supset I_1 \supset I_2 \supset I_3 \supset \dots$

(b) $I_n$ is not covered by any finite subcollection of $G_\alpha$

(c) If $x \in I_n$ and $y \in I_n$ then $|y-x| \leq 2^{-n}\delta$

Hence there is a point $x^* \in \cap I_n$ and for some $\alpha$ $x^* \in G_\alpha$. Since $G$ is open there is a neighborhood $N_r(x^*) \subset G_\alpha$. If $n$ is large enough that $2^{-n}\delta < r$ then given $p \in I_n$ $|x^* - p | < 2^{-n}\delta < r \implies p \in N_r(x^*) \implies I_n \subset G_\alpha$ contradicting the fact that $I_n$ cannot be covered by a finite subcollection of $\{ G_\alpha\}$

Comment: This seems difficult. An arbitrary open cover could be very complicated, which makes it tricky to show that there must be a finite subcover.

Comment: That is what makes the problem interesting.

Comment: How does your proof work out in the case that $k=1$? That would be a good place to start.

Comment: Also, somewhere in your proof there must be a step which uses the completeness property of the real numbers (either directly, or indirectly by quoting some lemma/proposition/theorem that does use it). Zeroing in on that step would be clarifying.

Comment: There cannot really be a constructive proof in this classical setting, as there are models of set theory where $[0,1]$ is not compact, e.g.

Comment: You *can* do it if you define $[0,1]$ constructively as well.

Comment: @LeeMosher could you clarify why the completeness of real numbers is relevant?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma If a proof by contradiction is possible we can't say the statement isn't true as its been proven.

Comment: @Joe If you're a constructivist you don't accept proof by contradiction as valid, just that $[0,1]$ is not not compact (which does not imply compact in constructivist logic). But then you get into foundations of mathematics discussions.

Comment: @joe, the compactness of $[0,1]$ in the order topology is a direct consequence of the order completeness of $[0,1]$ plus the fact it has a minimum and a maximum.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So you really don't think a constructive proof is possible within Rudin's framework?

Comment: Do you accept Alexander's subbase lemma as valid? But the proof of that also uses a cover without a finite subcover as well (plus Zorn's lemma). You're going to have to accept some non-constructiveness, as $[0,1]$ itself is not a constructive object.

Comment: The completeness of the real numbers is relevant because the rational numbers satisfy all of the axioms of the real numbers except completeness, and the interval $[0,1]$ defined in the rational numbers is not compact.

Comment: I am not a constructivist; I do not believe proof by contradiction is invalid. I am simply interested in why some things are relatively easy to prove by contradiction but very difficult to prove directly. From a philosophy of mathematics perspective this is a fact I find counterintuitive. Also I think seeking alternative proofs in general is a good way of understanding problems on a deeper level. Some of the comments have mentioned ideas that are beyond the scope of my study thus far... but I am eager to continue learning when constructiveness is possible in mathematics and when it is not.

Comment: @Joe but why would it be counterintuitive for some proof methods to be very easy while some others very hard? I find this unsurprising at all. However, you might find this blog [post](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/when-is-proof-by-contradiction-necessary/) interesting.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I find it counterintuitive that some proofs are easy to prove by contradiction but hard to prove directly... even more counterintuitive that some proofs might not even be possible to prove directly. Thanks for the link I will check it out. The fact that it seem counterintuitive just means I have a lot more to learn. The more research I do the less counterintuitive it seems.

Answer (score 0):

[https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~malabika/teaching/ubc/fall18/math320/HW7-revised.pdf](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Emalabika/teaching/ubc/fall18/math320/HW7-revised.pdf)

This assignment provides an alternative way to prove it. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but I think there is an issue with the proof above.

Now Rudin proves that there is no sequence $I_1 \supset I_2 \ldots$ of $k$-cells with properties b and c.

Unfortunately this doesn't prove that the original $k$-cell can be covered with a finite subset of $\{G_{\alpha}\}$. Here is why. Suppose you do the subdivision of the original $k$-cell into $2^n$ smaller cells and you do the same to these cells, etc. . This forms a tree where $k$-cells are connected with their direct subdivision elements. Each path from the root of the tree(original $k$-cell) defines an $I_1 \supset I_2 \supset \ldots$ sequence. What is proven by Rudin is that for each of these sequences there is an $l \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $I_l \subseteq G_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$. Let's not subdivide further the cells with such property. These are the leafs. Now what's proven is that each leaf has finite depth, but the depths are not bounded and it's easy to construct a tree where each leaf has finite depth, but the tree has $\mathbb{N}$ leafs.

Comment: This is an interesting persective. But I feel you are overthinking this. Rudin's proof seems fine to me. Rudin's argument is as follows: He *assumes* that the $k$-cell cannot be covered by a finite subcover. He then constructs a sequence $I_1 \supset I_2 \supset \dotsc$ of closed subspaces all of which do not lie in a finite subcover. He then proves that some $I_l$ *does* lie in a finite subcover, which yields a contradiction. Hence, the assumption was wrong. Therefore, the negation of the assumption is true, i.e. the $k$-cell admits a finite subcover.

Comment: Yes, I think I was wrong on this one. I mean if you have a tree where each node has a constant degree but the tree has an infinite number of points then there must be an infinite path in the tree starting from the root, but Rudin just proved that such infinite path cannot exist.

Comment: By the way, what you were describing is (very much related to) [König's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_lemma), through wich compactness theorems enter graph theory and logic.

Comment: You don't actually need that. I mean in the above tree the degree of each node is constant. And if you have a tree with constant degree with a fixed depth you can have degree^{depth + 1} - 1 nodes in total which is finite thus you must have an infinite route if such a tree has an infinite number of nodes.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I was not at all suggesting (or denying) that you **need** König's lemma. I was merely offering you, or anyone else interested and reading this, a possible avenue to read on. Nothing more.